# Unable to add appcompact v7 library into my project?

Tags: android, android-library

I just want to add v7 lib to my existing project in order to add navigation drawer but my whole project gets error and it shows some error in console in the resource of v7 lib(android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19).

`android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.`

and many more.

I have changed the target version to  the higher level (Android 5.1.1 )and i have cleaned the project.Tried many alternative methods coudn't find the possible solution.

Comment: Add the errors in your post.

Comment: need more info to make discussion

Comment: Sorry i went offline,while typing..coudn't completed the ques.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the latest version of `appcompat` (which you are based on the existence of `values-v23`), you must set your `targetSdkVersion` to 23. For future reference, the `appcompat` version number always needs to be the same as your target SDK.

Comment: Add your `build.gradle` to the question

Comment: Eclipse isn't really supported any more, but basically you have to target Android 6.0 to use `appcompat` v23.

Comment: @AsifSb As Kane stated, I highly recommend you drop Eclipse and integrate Android Studio, the tool is supported, and is much more guided towards Android states and evolution. It is also free.